# Getting http 404 error in android simulator for couch base lite during replication

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

In my Mac 10.9.2
I installed couch base server and it is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8091`
It has it's default buckets including beer-sample

I started sync server as

```
./sync_gateway -bucket="beer-sample"
```

that logs following in console

```
14:00:55.903306 ==== Couchbase Sync Gateway/0.94 ====
14:00:55.979850 Configured Go to use all 2 CPUs; setenv GOMAXPROCS to override this
14:00:55.979985 Configured MaxFileDescriptors (RLIMIT_NOFILE) to 5000
14:00:56.005329 Opening db /beer-sample as bucket "beer-sample", pool "default", server <walrus:>
14:00:56.019242 Opening Walrus database beer-sample on <walrus:>
14:00:56.057276 Using default sync function 'channel(doc.channels)' for database "beer-sample"
14:00:56.057549 Starting profile server on 
14:00:56.057680 Starting admin server on 127.0.0.1:4985
14:00:56.090556 Starting server on :4984 ...
```

In android my replication code looks like

```
Replication pullReplication = database.createPullReplication("http://10.0.2.2:4984");
pullReplication.start();
```

Then i ran my android app in simulator and i logged error as in changeEventListener

```
        if (!replication.isRunning()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Replication is not running due to " + replication.getLastError().getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "Replication is not running due to " + replication.getLastError().getCause());
            Log.d(TAG, "Replication is not running due to " + replication.getLastError().getStackTrace());
            Log.d(TAG, "Replication is not running due to " + replication.getLastError().toString());
        }
```

that logged

```
04-04 14:04:18.402    1622-1644/com.couchbase.replicationsample.replicationsample D/HelloWorld﹕ Replication: Puller[http://10.0.2.2:4984] changed.
04-04 14:04:18.432    1622-1644/com.couchbase.replicationsample.replicationsample D/HelloWorld﹕ Replication is not running due to HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
04-04 14:04:18.454    1622-1644/com.couchbase.replicationsample.replicationsample D/HelloWorld﹕ Replication is not running due to null
04-04 14:04:18.502    1622-1644/com.couchbase.replicationsample.replicationsample D/HelloWorld﹕ Replication is not running due to [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@414efc88
04-04 14:04:18.502    1622-1644/com.couchbase.replicationsample.replicationsample D/HelloWorld﹕ Replication is not running due to com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Note: I am using 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1 because i read in forum that's how simulator maps the host machine. But i also tried 127.0.0.1 earlier which also gives the same result.
```

At the same time i am seeing in sync gateway console log a new entry like

```
14:05:13.532393 HTTP:  #006: GET /_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000
```

I tried to repeat this query in a browser like

```
> http://127.0.0.1:4984/_changes?feed=normal&heartbeat=300000
```

which is showing

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"unknown URL"}
```

What is the mistake i am doing here? I am new to couch base.

Comment: Use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, I did. Mentioned in my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get past this error:

Found a reference project in https://github.com/couchbaselabs/GrocerySync-Android

Key changes made to my original steps/code are

1. Executed sync gateway as `./sync_gateway -bucket="beer-sample" -url=“http://localhost:8091/beer-sample" -verbose`
2. added database in the Sync URL like "`http://10.0.2.2:4984/beer-sample`" i.e., `database.createPullReplication("http://10.0.2.2:4984/beer-sample");`
3. Ran into authorization error. To let anonymous access (for the time being) enabled GUEST account by executing below command in terminal

   curl -X PUT localhost:4985/beer-sample/_user/GUEST --data '{"disabled":false, "admin_channels":["public"]}'

Comment: This got me up and running quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

or create a config (e.g. config.json) for sync_gateway like this:

```
{
   "interface":":4984",
   "adminInterface":":4985",
   "log":["REST"],
   "databases":{
      "registratura7":{
         "server":"http://YOUR_IP:8091",
         "bucket":"registratura7",
         "sync":`function(doc) {channel(doc.channels);}`,
         "users": { "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] } }
      }
   }
}
```

then run your sync_gateway like this: sync_gateway config.json. This would enable GUEST account on CouchDB Gateway.